# cummerbund, scatterplots and a statistical value

Tags: r, correlation

I'm working in cummerbund with cuffdiff files from a RNA-Seq analysis. I made a scatterplot with two conditions, but I'd like to see de correlation value of my data. Is it possible? Is there a command to do this? Any idea? Thanks!!

Comment: Cummerbund is a special package of R designed to work with big biological data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is taken from the [seqanswers](http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=57973) thread about the same thing.

Suppose your working directory contains a directory of your cuffdiff output, say `cuffdiff_out`. Then you can run this to find the correlation of the FPKM values.

```
cuff_data <- readCufflinks("cuffdiff_out/")
m <- fpkmMatrix(genes(cuff_data))
cor(m[, 1], m[, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched decorrelation and find nothing significant I am guessing you mean the correlation.

You are looking for cor function. Just type ?cor into r and you will get the info. Here is an example.

```
> cor(1:5,1:5)
[1] 1
> cor(1:5,5:1)
[1] -1
```

Comment: Hi, You are right, correlation is what I want. But the problem is how to use this command with my data, is not that simple. Do you know something about CummeRbund? Thanks for your help.